Help needed in solving this initial boundary value problem.
Solve the initial value boundary problem:
$$u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}, \quad 0 < x < \infty, \quad t > 0,$$
$$u(x,0) = f(x), \quad 0 \leq x < \infty,$$
$$u_t(x,0) = g(x), \quad 0 \leq x < \infty,$$
$$u(0,t) = 0, \quad 0 \leq t < \infty.$$
First, I tried to find the general solution of the PDE $c^2u_{xx}-u_{tt}=0,0\lt x\lt\infty,t>0$ by first reducing it into a canonical form.
The characteristic equations are $\frac{dt}{dx}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{4c^2}}{2c^2}=\pm\frac{1}{c}.$
So, the characteristic curves are $x-ct=c_1$ and $ct+x=c_2$, where $c_1,c_2$ are constants of integration.
So, let $\xi=x-ct$ and $\eta=x+ct.$ With these change of variables we can transform the given PDE to $u_{\xi\eta}=0.$
Solving this we have, $u(\xi,\eta)=\phi(\xi)+\psi(\eta).$
This is equivalent to, $u(x,y)=\phi(x+ct)+\psi(x-ct).$
Now, applying the initial conditions, $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$ we have, $\phi(x)+\psi(x)=f(x)$ and $\phi(x)-\psi(x)=\frac 1c(\int_{x_0}^xg(\tau)d\tau+K,$ where, $x_0$ is any point in the domain of $g$ and $K$ is an arbitrary integration constant. The later equation was obtained on integrating the equation, $(\phi'(x)-\psi'(x))c=g(x).$
Solving for $\phi$ and $\psi$ and substituting them into the general solution $u(x,t)=\phi(x+ct)+\psi(x-ct)$ we get, $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[f(x+ct)+f(x-ct)]+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(\tau)d\tau.$

So, I could solve the problem using the initial value conditions but now, I have no idea how to use the boundary condition to make the $u(x,t)$ more precise so that it satisfies all the conditions.
I think, the process should be the same, i.e. $u(0,t)=0\implies u(0,t)=\frac{1}{2}[f(ct)+f(-ct)]+\int_{-ct}^{ct}g(\tau)d\tau =0.$
But now, I have no idea on how to proceed further? Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

These notes go through the problem in detail.

Mathematica's solution:
$$u(x,t)\to
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} \left(f\left(x-c t\right)+f\left(x+c t\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-c t}^{x+c t} g(\xi),\mathrm{d}\xi & x>c t\geq 0 \
\frac{1}{2} \left(f\left(x+c t\right)-f\left(c t-x\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{c t-x}^{x+c t} g(\xi),\mathrm{d}\xi & 0\leq x\leq c t \
\end{cases}$$
